# MYSQL: Merge datas with same id and put all the datas to another new column

Tags: mysql

Good day,

I have a problem regarding how to build my query in MYSQL.
I have this raw data.

```
ID       | NAME | VALUE | DESCRIPTION
ID-0001  | ARV1 | 10200 | First description
ID-0002  | ARV2 | 10300 | Second description
ID-0001  | ARV1 | 10400 | Added Description
```

And I want to achieve an output like this:
Where I want to merge the datas with the same ID and put the other tables in another column and with new column name.

```
ID       | NAME | VALUE 1 | DESCRIPTION  1      |  VALUE 2 |  DESCRIPTION 2     |
ID-0001  | ARV1 | 10200   | First description   |  10400   |  Added Description |
ID-0002  | ARV2 | 10300   | Second description  |          |                    |
```

I badly need help. Thanks!

Comment: What does the output look like for 6 rows of data?

Comment: This is like a pivot right?

Comment: I want to achieve the output with 6 rows.

Comment: if many rows ID-0001 in this table then what will your table look like. Suppose your example where ID-0001 = 2 rows if it is 4 rows then

Comment: I don't know anything about pivot, can you help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Comment: There should probably not more than four rows of ID-001

Comment: The maximum is two rows for each ID.

Comment: which mysql version you use?

Comment: mysql  Ver 8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2

Comment: Enumerate rows with the same ID in cte, then use 2 copies of it. PS. How to distinguish what data must be used for 1st columns pair and for 2nd one?

Comment: @blizzy please check below query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID wise row is serialized as per storing data in DB that's why ORDER BY is not use. This query is alternative of PIVOT. But if more row exists for a same ID then PIVOT is better option. If any primary key is existed in table then use that PK at ORDER BY clause after PRTITION BY.

```
-- MySQL (v5.8)
SELECT t.id
     , MAX(t.name) name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.row_num = 1 THEN value END) value1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.row_num = 1 THEN description END) description1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.row_num = 2 THEN value END) value2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t.row_num = 2 THEN description END) description2
FROM (SELECT *
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) row_num
      FROM test) t
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e4a5999a3536b9e042d7ed92fc392de7

Suppose table have a primary key column name p_id. Then ROW_NUMBER() will

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY p_id) row_num
```

**N.B:** By default p_id sorts the data in ascending order but if need descending order then use DESC.

Comment: ORDER BY is mandatory when ROW_NUMBER is used with an OVER clause.

Comment: No ORDER BY IS NOT mandatory. Please check my given url

Comment: @Madhukar *ORDER BY is mandatory* - no. But it provides definite ordering.

Comment: why negative vote for my answer. I don't totally understand that.

Comment: @Akina and Rahul - Oh okay, May be it is mandatory only in SQL Server.

Comment: @Madhukar do you give negative vote for missing ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME ORDER BY rowid) rn
    FROM test
)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.NAME, 
       t1.VALUE value1, t1.DESCRIPTION description1, 
       t2.VALUE value2, t2.DESCRIPTION description2
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
                AND t1.NAME = t2.NAME
                AND t2.rn = 2
WHERE t1.rn = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e10ac4664ef614300c23a987f83e805d

PS. If a column which defines the rows priority not exists (`rowid` in the fiddle - it can be, for example, the creation datetime or something else) then the data order of the values pairs is not determined.